# Sending a sms with the accelerometer on iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios4, sms, accelerometer

Can you send a sms using an accelerometer action instead of physically touching the screen in iOS 4. I know the send button is supposed to be tapped to trigger a sms but app's like Assault Alarm don't actually physically touch the send button the user just presses the centre of the screen. It suggests that maybe another user interaction can effect the send button.

Answer (score 0):

Other apps can intercept the accelerometer action and call the same selector as when a button is tapped. The problem is, you cannot do that with the SMS app.

One solution that comes to mind is using a web based service to send sms in a background thread.